# Value is undefined even after it is reinitialized

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am facing an issue of value being undefined even after initializing. Below is my code.

```
let fruits = config.fruits; // object of fruits
fruits = [{       // initialized
  quantity: 3,
  list: [],
}];
let pageNo = 0;

 for (let i = 0; i < fruitList.length; i += 1) { //Loop for iteration
   if ((i / 9) != 1) {
    fruits[pageNo].list.push({
     // body we need to push
      name: 'mango',
      subtype: 'alphonso',
  })
 } else {
   fruits[pageNo] = [{     //Reinitialized
     quantity: 3,
     list: [],
  }]
  fruits[pageNo].list.push({  // error on this line.
     // body we need to push
      name: 'mango',
      subtype: 'alphonso',
  })
 }
}
```

I have reinitialized the fruits array in else part but still I am getting an error saying - "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: You assign an array here `fruits[pageNo] = [{ quantity: 3, list: [], }]` but then you try to access `fruits[pageNo].list.push()`. Arrays don't have a `.list` property. Either you're assigning the wrong structure or you mean ` fruits[pageNo].push()` or maybe something different.

Comment: You've reinitialised `fruits[pageNo]` to an array with an object in it, not an object. Changing `fruits[pageNo] = [{ //Reinitialized quantity: 3, list: [],}]` to `fruits[pageNo] = { //Reinitialized quantity: 3, list: [], }` should fix it